# Pass URL path to ReportViewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, reportviewer

I have a method ddlCompanyList_SelectedIndexChanged that essentially uses a stored procedure to find the URL to my reports that is stored on a table. It also makes use of a reader to grab that url:

```
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string x = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
                test(x);

            }
        }

        else
        {
           /* Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");*/
        }

        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();
```

This URL will be stored in variable x and then passed onto my 'test' method:

```
protected void test(string x)
{
    Response.Write(x);
}
```

The result is, whenever a report is selected from my dropdown list, ddlCompanyList_SelectedIndexChanged will run to grab that reports URL before passing it to 'test'. The final step and one I am unsure about is how can I pass variable x into my ReportViewer:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Width="930px" Height="1000" Font-Size="8pt" ProcessingMode="Remote" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
        <ServerReport ReportPath="/Systems/test/Report 1" ReportServerUrl="http://test/ReportServer" />
            </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Right now I have manually added a ReportPath, however I am hoping to find a way to specificy that the ReportPath will always be the value of my variable x.

Thank you for any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this:

```
this.ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = x;
```